# How to configure "All APIs" policy using Bicep?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-api-management, azure-bicep

I configured APIM in Bicep like this:

```
resource apiManagement 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service@2019-12-01' = {
  name: appName
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: 'Developer'
    capacity: 1
  }
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  properties: {
    publisherEmail: publisherEmail
    publisherName: publisherName
  }
  resource policy 'policies@2021-01-01-preview' = {
    name: 'allApis'
    properties: {
      value: allOperationsPolicy
      format: 'xml'
    }
  }
}
```

And I can create 'api-read' API with some policy using syntax like this:

```
resource apiRead 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis@2021-01-01-preview' = {
  parent: apiManagement
  name: 'api-read'
  properties: {
    displayName: 'API Read'
    subscriptionRequired: true
    path: 'read'
    protocols: [
      'https'
    ]
    isCurrent: true
    authenticationSettings: {
      oAuth2: {
        authorizationServerId: authServer.name
      }
    }
  }
  resource policyAllOperationsRead 'policies@2021-01-01-preview' = {
    name: 'policy'
    properties: {
      value: myPolicyHere
      format: 'xml'
    }
  }
}
```

But how can I add policy to All API's (global policy) using Bicep, to have it here?

[image: screenshot of APIM]

I have tried like this:

```
resource apiManagement 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service@2019-12-01' = {
  name: appName
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: 'Developer'
    capacity: 1
  }
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  properties: {
    publisherEmail: publisherEmail
    publisherName: publisherName
  }
  
}

resource policy 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis/policies@2021-01-01-preview' = {
  parent: apiManagement
  name: 'allApis'
  properties: {
    value: allOperationsPolicy
    format: 'xml'
  }
}
```

But I got error:

> The property "parent" expected a value of type "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis" but the provided value is of type "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service@2019-12-01"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all I was able to do it like that:

```
resource apiManagement 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service@2019-12-01' = {
  name: appName
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: 'Developer'
    capacity: 1
  }
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  properties: {
    publisherEmail: publisherEmail
    publisherName: publisherName
  }
  resource policy 'policies@2021-01-01-preview' = {
    name: 'policy'
    properties: {
      value: allOperationsPolicy
      format: 'xml'
    }
  }
}
```

Note that name can only be "policy"

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.apimanagement/service/policies?pivots=deployment-language-bicep), policies can be added for all apis like that:

```
resource policy 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/policies@2021-01-01-preview' = {
  parent: apiManagement
  name: 'allApis'
  properties: {
    value: allOperationsPolicy
    format: 'xml'
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried similar solution, but I've got an error "Name should only be 'policy' for policies entity.". So I changed "allApis" to "policy" and it works.

Comment: does the api-version doing anything ?